# Testing function calls in Jest after button click (mocking fetch calls)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, fetch, react-testing-library

I am running Jest test suites for a React SPA. I am trying to write tests for the sign-in page. I have a number of functions that should be called if the result of the sign-in attempt is a 404, but I can't figure out why they aren't being called.

I am trying to mock the fetch call that authenticates the user and make sure the correct functions are called afterwards. What the code below is attempting to do is:

- create a fake resolved promise
- setup the mock fetch to return that resolved promise
- fire the events to mimic what a user would do (input username/password, click 'sign in')
- wait for all promises to be resolved
- check that my functions have been called

```
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";
import SignIn from "./signIn";
import 'jest-dom/extend-expect';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';

const mockResponse = (status: number, response: BodyInit) => {
    const fetchResponse: Response = new Response(response, {status:status});
    return fetchResponse;
}

describe("<SignIn>", () => {
it("sets basic creds, auth header, usingIMS, and authenticated when it gets a 404", async () => {
    const setBasicCreds = jest.fn();
    const setAuthHeader = jest.fn();
    const setUsingIms = jest.fn();
    const setAuthenticated = jest.fn();
    const baseUrl = 'https://testUrl';

    const fakePromise = Promise.resolve(mockResponse(404, JSON.stringify({message: "test"})));
    window.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => {
        return fakePromise;
    });

    const { getByTestId } = render(<SignIn baseUrl={baseUrl} setBasicCreds={setBasicCreds} setAuthenticated={setAuthenticated}
    setAuthHeader={setAuthHeader} setUsingIms={setUsingIms} connectionName={signInProps.connectionName}></SignIn>);

    const username: HTMLElement = getByTestId("signInUsername");
    fireEvent.change(username, {
        target: { value: 'username' },
      });

    const password: HTMLElement = getByTestId("signInPassword");
    fireEvent.change(password, {
        target: { value: 'password' },
      });

    const submitButton: HTMLElement = getByTestId("signInSubmitButton");
    fireEvent.click(submitButton);

    await Promise.all([fakePromise]);
    expect(setBasicCreds).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(setAuthHeader).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(setUsingIms).toHaveBeenCalledWith(false);
    expect(setAuthenticated).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Authenticated');
    });
});
```

When the test suite is run, it fails on the first `expect`, saying the `setBasicCreds` was never called. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on my question much later, the answer is to use integration testing. What I was trying to do makes much more sense for integration testing using a framework like Cypress than the Jest unit tests.